# Python Subprocess, using rsync with ssh key file, error with method Call

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, subprocess, rsync

I've got this command to sync a data file from a remote server, and I'm using a ssh key file as method for authentication. My original command in bash it's:

```
rsync -az -e 'ssh -i my_key.pem' admin@192.168.0.10:/export/home/admin/monitor_dir/monitor_srv1.dat .
```

And that works just fine, it transfers the file but when I try to use Python subprocess library method call, to run the bash command from this python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import subprocess

server = ['192.168.0.10', '/export/home/admin/monitor_dir/', 'srv1']

subprocess.call(['rsync', '-az', '-e', '\'ssh', '-i', 'my_key.pem\'', 'admin@{0}:{1}monitor_{2}.dat'.format(server[0],server[1],server[2]), '.'])
```

This it's the error shown:

```
rsync: link_stat "/Users/works/LUIS/scripts_py/my_key.pem'" failed: No such file or directory (2)

rsync: link_stat "/Users/works/LUIS/scripts_py/admin@192.168.0.10:/export/home/admin/monitor_dir/monitor_srv1.dat" failed: No such file or directory (2)

rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-51/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

I tried the method run and call too, but I don't know what I am doing wrong, or even if there is another way to execute the rsync command using python?

I'm using:

```
-Python 3.5.0
-GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
-rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rsync -az -e 'ssh -i my_key.pem' ...
```

When you run rsync from your shell, the single quotes are shell syntax to treat the string `ssh -i my_key.pem` as a single command-line argument, instead of three arguments separated by spaces. When your shell invokes the `rsync` program, rsync will have this list of command-line arguments:

```
rsync
-az
-e
ssh -i my_key.pem
...
```

In the python version:

```
subprocess.call(['rsync', '-az', '-e', '\'ssh', '-i', 'my_key.pem\'', ...
```

You're passing these command-line arguments to rsync:

```
rsync
-az
-e
'ssh
-i
my_key.pem'
```

You don't need the escaped quotes here--the quotes in the original are *shell* syntax, and you're not using a shell to invoke rsync here. You want to invoke rsync like this:

```
subprocess.call(['rsync', '-az', '-e', 'ssh -i my_key.pem', ...
```

As for this error:

> rsync: link_stat "/Users/works/LUIS/scripts_py/admin@...

This may be a side effect of the other error. Rsync has decided it's trying to do a local->remote copy instead of a remote->local copy, and it's trying to interpret the "admin@..." argument as a local filename.